# "torch cuda version not installed/working" on Mac

Tags: python, pytorch

I use Cellpose on my Mac and it worked perfectly fine. However, I abruptly closed once while it was training and now I cannot load multiple images to the GUI for segmentation and training.

When starting Cellpose with the command `python -m cellpose`
I get the following message:

cellpose version:   2.2.2
platform:           darwin
python version:     3.8.5
torch version:      2.0.1
2023-08-21 11:45:48,780 [INFO] TORCH CUDA version not installed/working.

If I try to import a folder this message pops up:
**[CRITICAL] ERROR: could not read file, 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim'**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/zeeko/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cellpose/gui/gui.py", line 909, in dropEvent
io._load_image(self, filename=files[0])
File "/Users/zeeko/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cellpose/gui/io.py", line 129, in _load_image
_initialize_images(parent, image, resize=parent.resize, X2=0)
File "/Users/zeeko/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cellpose/gui/io.py", line 141, in _initialize_images
if image.ndim > 3:
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim'**

I have tried to solve this problem like others did on Stack Overflow by installing pytorch with `conda install pytorch cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch` (I've tried with cudatoolkit = 11.2 and 11.3) but it doesn't work. This is the message I get:

*failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- cudatoolkit=10.1*

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the channel from PyTorch to NVIDIA:

`conda install cudatoolkit=11.3 -c nvidia`

If you still can't find it, try running `conda search cudatoolkit`.

Comment: I've tried it - it does not work. After running the conda search cudatoolkit I get this: Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
cudatoolkit                      9.0      h41a26b3_0  pkgs/main 

But the conda install still doesn't work.

Comment: @Zeeko Try running `conda update conda`, then `conda update --all`

Comment: I have tried that too and it doesn't help. However, even after running both of them, I get this 
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.10.3
  latest version: 23.7.2

Please update conda by running
$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

But no matter how many times i repeat that process I get the same massage.

Comment: You're using a very old version of Conda. My recommendation would be to uninstall and reinstall Conda manually.

Comment: I just updated my conda to the latest version (don't ask how bc I myself don't know how). The problem persists...

Comment: Oh yeah, you're using a mac. For me on Linux the command worked fine, but on Apple CUDA doesn't work at all since High Sierra (thank Apple for that) so the solution of reinstalling cudatoolkit won't work. Can you reinstall cellpose?

Comment: I tried that too :P

Comment: If you're using M1, try this: https://cellpose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#m1-mac-installation

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to uninstall and then reinstall the newest versions of each and every dependency separately. They can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/cellpose/